# openssl upgrade | fail validating certificate

Tags: openssl, certificate

I am working on CentOS7 machine, compiled my code with static openssl version 1.1.0l where my machine has version 1.0.2k

When I try to authenticate to the server i get these error message:
error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate.

I decided to compile openssl standalone and run verification with it.

It seems like the handshake process with my server(which didn't change) fails with the new version and I'm trying to figure out the cause.

Running the following command with both openssl version:

> openssl s_client -showcerts -connect server:port

Resulted with failure with the newer one.
A diff of the result:

**Old 1.0.2k (handshake successful)**:

```
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

**New 1.1.0l (fails handshake)**:

```
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

I would appreciate with help understanding the difference, and why are they different.

Edit:

The upgrade

Comment: They don't seem to be using the same truststore. Are/were both of these yum packages, and from the same repository? Are/were they both installed, and if so which (if either) is in the official locations /usr/bin /usr/lib64 etc and which isn't? If you can run both, do `openssl version -d` and see what directories they report, and check the file `cacert.pem` or subdirectory `certs` at each. PS: this is not a programming or development question, and likely to be closed.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085
Only the older version 1.0.2 was installed, the 1.1.0 was used as a standalone executable.

The new version wasn't installed using yum.

1.0.2 openssl version -d:
/etc/pki/tls

1.1.0 openss version -d:
/etc/ssl
However, I see a symbolic link from /etc/ssl/certs -> /etc/pki/ts/certs.

btw, running the above openssl connect command with -CAfile <path_to_cert>

Comment: The package version uses /etc/pki/tls/cert.pem (supplied by the ca-certificates package) which links to a file containing common roots; /etc/pki/tls/certs exists but doesn't have the hashnamed files OpenSSL requires so it can't be used. /etc/ssl/certs links to /etc/pki/tls/certs which as I said can't be used, and /etc/ssl/cert.pem doesn't exist, so that version doesn't work. Your comment seems to have been truncated, but if you meant giving the new version `-CAfile` and (either name of) the file used by the package version causes it to use the same truststore, yes.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks.

Do you have any suggestions of how to resolve this/workaround? Tried executing openssl rehash to generated (hopefully) the hashnamed files you mentioned.

Comment: rehash where? /etc/pki/tls/certs? Do you have individual files for all needed roots/anchors there? My CentOS7(.7) doesn't, and in general I don't recommend changing files or directories that installed packages want to manage. rehash only adds the hash _names_ to existing certs, it can't create certs because it has no way of knowing what certs you want to trust (other than you providing them in files). If you want to create a CAdir I'd put it somewhere else. ...

Comment: ... In any case, you can have your built program reference either the CentOS-supplied (known-good) file (but not dir), or your own file and/or dir, by (1) using options like `-CAfile -CApath` (2) usually by setting env vars `SSL_CERT_{FILE,DIR}` -- see the man page for SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths (3) rebuilding with configure option --openssldir (applies to both file and dir, FWTW)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks.
The weird thing i am facing is that I have an executable which runs just fine on one CentOS machine and fails on another. The machines should be identical, but i guess they are not somehow and I'm trying to figure out what might be the issue.

I tracked the execution with strace, and saw this difference:
Failing handshakes is looking for certificates in:
/var/ssl/cert.pem
Working handshake is looking for cerificates in:
/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem

I wonder how it can be different, as the paths are defined at compile time(SSL_CERT_DIR)

Comment: Is there some configuration that can change the lookup path of the openssl?

Another thing is, i see that SSL_CERT_DIR env is: /etc/pki/tls/certs but the lookup path is /etc/pki/ca-trust/... (on the working host). Why are they different?

Comment: I though you were running differently-built executables, not the same one; I'm even less clear now what you're doing. "OPENSSLDIR" (displayed by `openssl version -d`) is set at compile time, but envvars `SSL_CERT_{FILE,DIR}` can be set at runtime and override it IF the program uses SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths as I referenced before. I have 1.0.2k-19.el7 from a standard install and it defaults to _file_ /etc/pki/tls/cert.pem which actually symlinks to /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem but my strace doesn't show that; same exe fails if I set SSL_CERT_FILE (not DIR) wrong.

Comment: /var/ssl/anything is clearly wrong for CentOS (other Unices sometimes used /var for 'third-party' things, but not CentOS). Check what exe and lib you are running in the failure case, how the lib was built, and whether SSL_CERT_FILE is set; cert.pem is intended to be a file not a dir.

Comment: It's the same exe\lib combination executed on the two machines.

SSL_CERT_FILE and SSL_CERT_DIR are not set during runtime, only at compile time. And as it's the same executable, they are the same(verified):

SSL_CERT_FILE env is: /opt/_internal/certs.pem
SSL_CERT_FILE not set in runtime
SSL_CERT_DIR env is: /etc/pki/tls/certs
SSL_CERT_DIR not set in runtime

Comment: Now I'm trying to figure why on the "bad" machine, the path the exe tries to search in is /var/ssl. That should be the cause for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, adding solution here.

Once starting to work with openssl version > 1.0.2 on centos7 machines, there seems to be a behavioural change in the root certs resolution path.

Openssl goes through a predefined list of cert store locations, however, once it encounters a cert.pem file in /val/ssl it will test it and if fails to validate the remote using it, will stop the lookup in the remaining locations.
It happens that the good certificate (in my client's env) /etc/ssl is searched by openssl after /var/ssl and therefor the failure.

My solution was to programmatically choose the correct cert.pem in case openssl fails (without altering the openssl version of the machine, which was prohibited).

Comment: I'm sorry but this is nonsense; there is no predefined list or version dependency (except 3.0, not relevant here). If program calls `load_verify_locations` it uses (exactly) one file and/or one dir per the call. If program calls `default_verify_paths` it uses one file and one dir determined EITHER from envvar(s) `SSL_CERT_{FILE,DIR}` OR openssldir which is set _at build time_, as I said 2 months ago. _CentOS packagers_ set this _for ALL versions_ to `/etc/pki/tls`, while the 1.1.0 you are using apparently was built by someone else who set `/etc/ssl`; that could be done for any version.

Comment: But `/var/ssl` is not `/etc/ssl`. I would go to the point your app calls `default_verify_paths` and show `getenv("SSL_CERT_FILE") getenv("SSL_CERT_DIR")` and `OpenSSL_versionOPENSSL_DIR)` from `#include <openssl/opensslv.h>` (see the man page) and if the locations actually used aren't determined entirely from those three values as per the man page the code you're running isn't really OpenSSL, it's some impostor or fake.

Comment: I am writing in Rust using a lib called "reqwest" and I didn't notice an access to this api directly.
Using strace on the executable (my software), I could see the paths that openssl tries to open while attempting to find a certificate. It scan multiple paths, until reaches the /var/ssl, finds the cert.pem and tries to validate the remote with it. Once it fails, it doesn't continue to the remaining possible paths.

Comment: Regarding you comment about the env variables, 
SS_CERT_DIR pointed to the correct location /etc/ssl and the SSL_CERT_FILE wasn't configured.

the openssl dir from the version was correct as well (/etc/ssl).

I can provide the source code in rust if it helps + upload the vm if it you are intrested.

Comment: (Sorry, I misplaced this bookmark and just found it again.) You said /etc/ssl/certs -> /etc/pki/tls/certs which is NOT correct for SSL_CERT_DIR. It may be that Rust or that library detects this and does some kind of alternative or search, but OpenSSL (which is what your question said) does not. Sorry, I don't have time to learn a whole new language and environment to address one question, so I guess I'll have to leave this unresolved.